# Accurate identities related to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}x^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^4}x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, bessel-functions, elliptic-integrals

Some time ago while playing around with maths, I derived the following pair of formulae:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}x^n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{4x\cos^2\theta}\;d\theta\tag{1}$$
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^4}x^n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}I_{0}\left(4\sqrt{x}\cos\theta\right)\;d\theta\tag{2}$$

as well as the following generalizations:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!^m}{(n!)^{2m+1}}x^n=\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^m\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ldots\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{4^{m}x\prod_{k=1}^{m}\cos^2\theta_k}\;d\theta_1\ldots\;d\theta_m\tag{3}$$
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!^m}{(n!)^{2m+2}}x^n=\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^m\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ldots\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}I_0\left(2^{m+1}\sqrt{x}\prod_{k=1}^{m}\cos\theta_k\right)\;d\theta_1\ldots\;d\theta_m\tag{4}$$

(In what follows $J_0$ and $I_0$ and [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind) are [modified Bessel](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) functions respectively of the first kind). The method I used to find these was extremely formal (in the second sense of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53969/what-does-formal-mean/53977#53977) answer) and [I know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988553/criteria-for-formally-derived-euler-maclaurin-type-formula) that such derivations can give spurious results, so **my question** is: are these formulae correct?

(Note that I have asked them in the same question because my derivation below proved them together, requiring one to prove the other. These series could be written in terms of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) but [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html) does not seem to contain any formulae like these involving powers of binomial coefficients in the [numerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)) of the summand.)

[**Edit**: I have just noticed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824437/prove-int-0-pi-2-j-0-cos-x-dx-frac-pi2-leftj-0-left-frac12?rq=1) which appears to mention a special case of $(2)$ (modified by the formal identity $J_0(ix)=I_0(x)$).]

---

**Outline of formal derivation**: I started with the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) formula $L\left[t^{\frac{n}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-\frac{n}{2}}J_n(2\sqrt{ut})f(u)\;du\right](s)=\frac{1}{s^{n+1}}L[f(t)]\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)$ from Borelli and Coleman's *Differential Equations: a modelling perspective* (the proof is not too difficult), which formally implies that if $f(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^n$ then:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}t^n}{n!}=L^{-1}\left[\frac{f(\frac{1}{s})}{s}\right](t)=\int_0^\infty J_0(2\sqrt{ut})L^{-1}[f(s)](u)\;du\tag{5}$$

Taking $f(t)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-t}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!t^n}{(n!)^{2}4^n}$ (a [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)) in $(5)$, by [convolution](http://www3.ul.ie/%7Emlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap20/20_6.pdf) and [shifting](http://17calculus.com/laplace-transforms/shifting-theorems/) we get $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!t^n}{(n!)^{3}4^n}=L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{s}}}\right](t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^t \frac{e^u}{\sqrt{u(t-u)}}\;du$, and $\color{#ff0000}{(1)}$ follows by setting $u=\frac{t\left(\cos(2\theta)+1\right)}{2}$. Taking $f(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(n!)^3}t^n$ in $(5)$ and using $(1)$ and elementary [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae) gives $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(n!)^4}t^n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty J_0(2\sqrt{ut})L^{-1}\left[e^{-2s}\int_0^\pi e^{-2s\cos\theta}\;d\theta\right](u)\;du$. But making the transformation $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{t-2}{2}\right)$, the argument of the inverse Laplace transform becomes $\int_0^4\frac{e^{-st}}{\sqrt{4t-t^2}}\;dt$ which is the Laplace transform of $\frac{1-H(t-4)}{\sqrt{4t-t^2}}$ ($H(t)$ is the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)) so our formula reduces to $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty J_0(2\sqrt{ut})\frac{1-H(u-4)}{\sqrt{4u-u^2}}\;du$ which by taking $u=2(1+\cos2\theta)$ and formally setting $J_0(ix)=I_0(x)$ gives $\color{#ff0000}{(2)}$.

Using the resulting formula $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^4}(-1)^n t^{2n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}J_{0}\left(4t\cos\theta\right)\;d\theta$ and taking the Laplace transform of both sides and interchanging integral and Laplace transform gives $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!^2}{(n!)^4}\frac{(-1)^n}{ s^{2n+1}}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+16\cos^2\theta}}\;d\theta$, which gives:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!^2}{(n!)^4}(-1)^n t^n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+16t\cos^2\theta}}\;d\theta\tag{6}$$

This is an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) I believe. Applying $(5)$ to this, interchanging integral and Laplace transform, applying convolution and shifting, and taking $u=\frac{t}{2}(1+\cos2\varphi)$ lets us arrive at:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!^2}{(n!)^5}x^n=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{16x\cos^2\theta\cos^2\varphi}\;d\theta\;d\varphi\tag{7}$$

The methods of deriving $(2)$ from $(1)$ and of deriving $(7)$ from $(2)$ may be easily extended to an [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) deriving $\color{#ff0000}{(3)}$ and $\color{#ff0000}{(4)}$.

---

**Accuracy**: The error of $(1)$ for $x=0.02$ according to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((sum%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity%20((((2n)!))%2F((n!)%5E3))*(0.02%5En)))-(2%2Fpi)*(integral%20theta%20from%200%20to%20pi%2F2%20of%20e%5E(4*0.02*(cos(theta)%5E2)))) is on the order of $10^{-16}$ which seems extremely small although I am not sure about the sizes of errors in Wolfram|Alpha (and there are [very accurate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130823/do-you-know-any-almost-identities) [near identities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html); I have also derived [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089898/very-accurate-approximations-for-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracnan-1-and) identities with errors of $10^{-16}$ which appear to be mere approximations). I am not sure about the accuracy of $(2)$, $(3)$, or $(4)$ but noting the relation of $(6)$ to [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) we get the following [$AGM$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) formula:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!^2}{(n!)^4}x^n=\frac{1}{AGM(\sqrt{1-16x},1)}\tag{8}$$

whose error at $x=0.02$ [appears](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity%20((((2n)!)%5E2)%2F((n!)%5E4))*(0.02%5En))-(1%2Fagm(sqrt(1-16*0.02),1))) to be also on the order of $10^{-16}$. This seems to imply that the derivation may still be on the right track when $(6)$ is shown.

So **my question** is: Are some or all of the above (highlighted) identities correct?

Comment: It is worth noting that *Mathematica* evaluates the following:  `2/Pi Integrate[Exp[4 x Cos[t]^2], {t, 0, Pi/2}] - 
 Sum[(2 n)!/(n!)^3 x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]` and gives `0` as the result.

Comment: @heropup Thank you very much. That gives me a little more confidence in the result. I wonder about the generalization $(3)$?

Comment: It does appear to generalize at least for the small cases of $m$ I was able to evaluate in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Your first formula is certainly correct as can be seen by expanding $e^{4x\cos^{2}\theta}$ into an infinite series and then using term by term integration. Same is true of $(6)$ and the last ago identity.

Comment: I would advise you to use techniques which are analytical (rather than formal) to derive such formulas because then you will know the values of the parameters involved in the formulas for which these are true. It is nice to get intuition about such identities using formal methods, but very necessary to prove them using analytical methods. See such a journey of formal to analytical in my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/arithmetic-geometric-mean-of-gauss.html

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your helpful comments. In your first comment, are you getting at using the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ and turning the problem into integrals of $\frac{1}{(\cos{x})^k}$?

Comment: @Anon: yes that's exactly what I am trying to say.

Comment: I am not much familiar with Bessel functions but I believe if you their power series and then perform term by term integration you will reach your formulas. Also since you seem to apply methods related to Laplace transform you should check the exact conditions under which the Laplace transform formulas work so that the formal method gets its justification directly instead of deriving the formulas using some other independent methods.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ah, now I see that. That's a good insight, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. I wonder whether something similar might apply to the other formulae. I think it's just $(3)$ and $(4)$ that haven't been verified yet, but heropup says that $(3)$ does appear to work. Hopefully someone can write up an answer for me to accept anyway. By the way I love the AGM-elliptic integral journey you present in your post. With regards to the Laplace transform formulae, I made a few very formal steps (e.g. using Heaviside function), so I'm not sure I'll be able to get good conditions there.

Comment: I would have written an answer, but right now I am using smartphone and it is difficult to type math Jax with such devices. Maybe later when I get to my laptop I will write a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

> **Herein we present solutions to the $(1)$ and $(3)$ in the OP based on exploiting the uniform convergence of the series for $e^x$ on compact intervals.  To that end, we proceed.**

---

To show that $(1)$ in the OP is correct, we proceed as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{4x\cos^2(\theta)}\,d\theta&=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\cos^{2n}(\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\frac12 B\left(\frac12,n+\frac12\right)\\\\
&=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(n+1/2}{\Gamma(n+1)}\\\\
&=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt\pi(4x)^n}{(n!)^2}\Gamma(n+1/2)\\\\
&=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt\pi(4x)^n}{(n!)^2}\frac{\sqrt \pi(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\,(2n)!}{(n!)^3}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

We can use the previous result to show that $(3)$ in the OP is indeed correct.  Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\overbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cdots \int_0^{\pi/2}}^{m\,\text{ terms}} e^{4^mx\prod_{k=1}^m \cos^2{\theta_k}}\,d\theta_1\cdots\,d\theta_m&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(4^{mk})x^k}{k!}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k}(\theta)\,d\theta\right)^m\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(4^{mk})x^k}{k!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(2k)!}{4^k(k!)^2}\right)^m\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left((2k)!\right)^m}{(k!)^{2m+1}}\,x^k
\end{align}$$

After multiplying by $(2/\pi)^m$, we arrive at the result $(3)$!

Comment: +1 This is a really nice answer that answers my questions about $(1)$ and $(3)$. I had been wondering how to possibly get rid of the multiple integral in $(3)$, but I hadn't thought of that nice simple way of proceeding. I wonder if a similar method could be used for $(2)$ and $(4)$?

Comment: @Anon Thank you!  Much appreciative.  -Mark